# Custom View Modifier to run code on first appear in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have read this code here and implemented it but its not working as expected https://gist.github.com/mattyoung/0deb368e64fe8e06a42412ecedc34604

The code I have implemented is as follows.

```
struct MainContent: View {
var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            // below is a list of buttons that changed the selectedNavigation
            NavigationListView()
        } detail: {
            getDetailView()
        }
    }

    func getDetailView() -> some View {
        Group {
            switch navigationVM.selectedNavigation {
            case .home:
                PdfPrinterView()
            case .settings:
                SettingsView()
            case .profile:
                ProfileView()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PdfPrinterView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeaderView()
            PdfScrollView()
        }
        .onFirstAppear { action() }

    }
    func action() {
        // call function 1 time from vm
        print("On first appear")
    }
}

extension View {
    func onFirstAppear(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(FirstAppear(action: action))
    }
}

private struct FirstAppear: ViewModifier {
    let action: () -> Void

    // Use this to only fire your block one time
    @State private var isFirstAppear = true

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        content.onAppear {
            if isFirstAppear {
                print("First")
                isFirstAppear = false
                action()

            } else {
                print("Second")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Every time i go back to the view, Its always as if it resets and is the first time.

When I change the navVM.selectedNavigation meaning I leave the PdfPrinterView, and then I change again back to viewing the pdfPrinterView this is the output I get.

```
// DEBUG CONSOLE OUTPUT:
// I go to the view
First
On first appear
// I leave the view
// go back to view
First
On first appear
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "go back to the view"? You should include a [mre] that includes whatever navigation you're doing.

Comment: I updated it to show where the navigation is. Is simple really, the detail view of the mac app is based off the navVM.selecetedNavigation. 

What I mean by leaving the view is changing the selectedNavigation and leaving the view, then changing the selectedNavigation again and having the view reappear.

Comment: You need something that lives longer than the View

Comment: You are storing `isFirstAppear` inside the modifier itself. Instead store it as a state in `PdfPrinterView` and pass as @Binding to the modifier. Or, if you want a complete guarantee that the value is not reset even if the parent view is recreated, use something like UserDefaults to preserve it

Comment: @timbretimbre youre right, I added onDissapear to the view modifier and it triggers as I change state to a new view. I have it built out now storing it in the ObservableObject class to preserve it. 
I just thought this looked like a clean implementation from the article. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue lies in the usage of the `@State` property wrapper in the `FirstAppear` modifier. The `@State` property is scoped to the view, and when you navigate away from the view and come back, the state is reset to its initial value, which is `true`. As a result, the `isFirstAppear` is always set to `true` on reappearing, causing the `action()` to be executed again.

To ensure that the `isFirstAppear` state persists across the view's lifetime, you should use `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject` property wrappers. Here's how you can modify the `FirstAppear` modifier:

```swift
private struct FirstAppear: ViewModifier {
    let action: () -> Void

    // Use @StateObject to persist the state across view's lifetime
    @StateObject private var isFirstAppear = FirstAppearState()

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {

        content.onAppear {
            if isFirstAppear.value {
                print("First")
                isFirstAppear.value = false
                action()
            } else {
                print("Second")
            }
        }
    }
}

// Create a separate class to hold the isFirstAppear state
private class FirstAppearState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value: Bool = true
}
```

By using `@StateObject`, the `FirstAppearState` instance will be retained across view appearances, and the `isFirstAppear` property will persist its value correctly, preventing the `action()` from being called every time you return to the view.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow,  Hing Tat Tsang!

Many of your answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.